# Create a dynamic UpdateOnly Expression in Servicestack Ormlite

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We currently have logic in our code to ignore properties that have an ignore value (for example if a `int` propertie has the value `Int32.MinValue + 1` then we will not include it in out SQL update.

Can I build up the onlyFields `Expression<Func<T, TKey>> onlyFields` object from my object? Is there any way I can loop all properties in the object and build up the onlyFields Expression from it?

```cs
public void Update(SSDataProduct dbProduct)
{
    using (var db = DbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
    {
        db.UpdateOnly(dbProduct,
            onlyFields: p => new { p.ProductName, p.Density },  // <-- needs to be dynamic
            where: p => p.Id == dbProduct.Id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an Anonymous Type dynamically in C# is the same as creating a normal type, [by using Reflection.Emit](http://benohead.com/create-anonymous-types-at-runtime-in-c-sharp/).

But in this case it would be easier to use the `SqlExpression` overload, e.g:

```
db.UpdateOnly(dbProduct, q => q
    .Update(new[]{ "Field1" }.ToList())
    .Where(p => p.Id == dbProduct.Id));
```

Comment: I can't get this code to work for me I get the following error. http://imgur.com/k20reCE

Comment: @BjarkiHeiðar Updated the example. The overload that accepts a `SqlExpression<T>` doesn't contain a lambda for **where** since it should've be added to the SqlExpression.